# HTML background overlapping body background

Tags: css, background

I have a background image on the html and the body tags as I have a repeating background on the html that I want to grow in height with the content. On top of this is the body background image - which is the main background image (that appears to dissolve into the html image, but it's just overlapping it).

This is working fine EXCEPT for when someone does a browser zoom. Oddly, the HTML background begins to creep over the body background on the right hand side.

```
html {
margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0;
background: #000000 url("menu/images/redline2.jpg") repeat-y center;
}

body {
margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0;
background: url("menu/images/about_bg2.jpg") no-repeat center;
}
```

Link to example of the issue: http://www.bitchofrome.com/about/about3.html

Comment: Doesn't happen for me in Chrome or FF. What browser are you seeing this in? BTW, it's not a great idea to have so much content in a background image—especially the text. That title text should be available in the HTML (even if hidden visually).

Comment: It's happening on FF (20), Safari (5), and IE9. On FF I had to zoom in 3-4 times before it started to happen, and it happens on the right side only.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common issue, and there's a simple solution for it. It often happens when you have a 100% width container with a background color or image. If you narrow down the browser window (or zoom) and then scroll right, the background has disappeared (as it doesn't get redrawn). The fix is to set a min-width on the outer container equal to (or greater than) the width of the inner elements.

In this case, what's needed is this:

```
html {min-width: 1100px;}
```